# How to create similar to my kotlin interceptor in swift?

Tags: swift, kotlin, interceptor

I have such interceptor in kotlin:

```
class AuthToken(context: Context) : Interceptor {
    var cont = context
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val sp = cont.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
        if (sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60
                && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!.isBlank()
                && !chain.request().url.toUrl().toString().contains("/login")) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
        }

        val initialRequest = if (sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60
                && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!.isBlank()
                && !chain.request().url.toUrl().toString().contains("/login")) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            requestBuilder(chain)
        } else {
            requestBuilder(chain)
        }


        val initialResponse = chain.proceed(initialRequest)

        return if (initialResponse.code == 401
                && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "").isNullOrBlank()
                && sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            initialResponse.close()
            val authorizedRequest = initialRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-type:", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + sp.getString("access_token", "")!!)
                    .build()
            chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
        } else {
            if (initialResponse.code == 500) {
                val thread = object : Thread() {
                    override fun run() {
                        Looper.prepare()
                        Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        Looper.loop()
                    }
                }
                thread.start()
            }
            initialResponse
        }
    }


    private fun updateAccessToken(context: Context) {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
        synchronized(this) {
            val tokensCall = accessTokenApi()
                    .getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!))
                    .execute()

            if (tokensCall.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = tokensCall.body()
                val editor = sp.edit()

                val localTime = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(tokensCall.headers()["Date"]!!)
                APICallRequests.setServerTime(localTime!!.time / 1000, context)

                editor.putString("access_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).access_token).apply()
                editor.putString("refresh_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).refresh_token).apply()
                editor.putLong("expires_in", responseBody!!.expires_in).apply()
            } else {
                when (tokensCall.code()) {
                    500 -> {
                        val thread = object : Thread() {
                            override fun run() {
                                Looper.prepare()
                                Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                Looper.loop()
                            }
                        }
                        thread.start()
                    }

                    401 -> {
                        APICallRequests.logOut(context)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    private fun requestBuilder(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Request {
        return chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                .build()
    }

    private fun accessTokenApi(): APIService {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
        dispatcher.maxRequests = 1


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

and how to create similar one for swift? I have created such interceptor:

```
extension URLRequest {
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.init(url: url)
        self.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        if !url.absoluteString.contains("/login") || url.absoluteString.contains("/refresh") {
            self.setValue("Bearer " + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access_token")!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }
    }
    
    func updateToken() -> String {
        return "token"
    }
    
    
}
```

but I can't create re-init url and I can't move forward. Maybe I did totally wrong interceptor and it can be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL" )!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "acc")
```

//            request.addValue("io=WLt40zNtw4N80D0QAAAR", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

```
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            print(response!)

          guard let data = data else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            return
          }
          print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
          completion(true)
```

////              semaphore.signal()
}

```
        task.resume()
```